# GROUP BY LINQ ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Let's suppose we have a Linq query like this:

```
int companyID = Convert.ToInt32(((UserIdentity)User.Identity).CompanyId);

var stock = from i in _stockService.GetStock()
            join ur in _inventoryService.GetInventory() on i.ProductID equals ur.Id
            where ur.ComapnyId == companyID
            select new StockVM
                       {
                           Product = ur.ItemName,
                           Quantity = i.Quantity,
                           BatchID = i.BatchID,
                           StockStatus = i.StockStatus,
                           MfgDate = i.MfgDate,
                           ExpDate = i.ExpDate,
                       };
```

Result

[image]

How to do a "Group By Product" with sum of `Quantity` in this linq query?

I need to only get max ExpDate firstOrDefault

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you want the result to be

**Product:** Desktop Accounting Software
**Qty:** 3
**BatchId:** 12345
**StockStatus:** _NIL
**MfgDate:** 3/29/2017 11:50:07 PM
**ExpDate:** 4/29/2017 11:50:07 PM

Comment: Seeing your previous question, you may think you're out of the woods now with this join, but since you're joining two `IEnumerable`s this will hit performance badly. You always pull the entire stock table into memory for each query. Really, you have no other option than a redesign.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
int companyID = Convert.ToInt32(((UserIdentity)User.Identity).CompanyId);

var stock = from i in _stockService.GetStock()
            join ur in _inventoryService.GetInventory() on i.ProductID equals ur.Id
            where ur.ComapnyId == companyID
group new { Quantity = i.Quantity } by new { ur.ItemName } into g
select new { Product = g.Key, TotalQuantity = g.Sum() } ).ToList() ;

List<StockVM> _lst = new List<StockVM>();
foreach(var item in stock ){
   StockVM row = new StockVM();
   row.Product = item.ItemName;
   //....
   _lst.Add(row);
}
```